# Python3 can't find a library

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pandas, ubuntu

First time I use Python.

On Ubuntu 20, I installed Python3 and created a first script in a virtualenv

I install Pandas library but get an error at the import : "no module named pandas"

I don't understand since directory where pandas was installed is in the path.

Installed dir :

```
pip show pandas
Location: ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

Path :

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

Answer (score 0):

Virtual environment is created only with python3 built-in packages.
To add pandas to your virtual environment, first `activate venv`, then install `pip install pandas`

I delete the question since I did not see right cause to close it.

Answer (score 0):

Found.

When I check the location for Pandas, I was not in the venv, and in the venv the location is not in the path ... I don't understand why but this answers this question and the new pb could be a new post ...